# Can I use variable substitution on $\delta$-$\epsilon$ proofs?

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

When I try to prove the continuity of a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ at $a$, can I make the substitution $x = a+y$, and thus:

$0 < |x-a| < \delta \implies |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$

becomes:

$0 < |y| < \delta \implies |f(a+y)-f(a)|<\epsilon$

I noticed that this simplifies things for some functions.

Comment: Sure, why not?  You are basically saying that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \lim_{y+a \to 0} f(y+a)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a name of a variable. Name it whatever you like. If you subsitute $y=x-a$ again, you get just $0<|x-a|<\delta \implies |f(a+x-a)-f(a)|=|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon $ again. I don't see any problem here. Do you have an example where you noticed something weird after substituting or where the proof significantly changed?

Comment: No i did not notice anything weird, it just simplifies the algebra, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you may .

The two statements $$0 < |x-a| < \delta \implies |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$$

$$ 0 < |y| < \delta \implies |f(a+y)-f(a)|<\epsilon$$ are equivalent.